# How to use 'stale?' in rails with eTAg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, etag

I am new to rails. I am trying to use cache and Etag to throw `304` status when the content is not modified.

My controller code is like this:

```
 def index
    @projects = @current_user.projects
    if stale?(@projects, public: true)
      render json: {"projects" => @current_user.projects.as_json}, status: 200
    end
  end
```

I am passing strong ETag with `If-None-Match` header but I am receiving the 200 status all the times irrespective of the `If-None-Match` header value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're running this in development, without setting `config.perform_caching` to true in `config/environments/development.rb`? Essentially caching is disabled by default in development, so to be able to play with this functionality, you need to enable it.

Comment: I have enabled the caching but even though it's not working